# Significato di "venire su" in questo contesto

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Ferito a morte*, di Raffaele La Capria, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> «… oggi non vanno tanto per il sottile, basta che puoi puntare perdere ed *eventualmente* pagare, vieni accolto a braccia aperte in qualsiasi Circolo. E poi si sa come va a finire con questa nuova gente **venuta su** che si va facendo così invadente: questo non ha pagato, quello ha fatto troppi debiti, quell’altro firma assegni a vuoto. Una volta queste cose nel caso peggiore si risolvevano col classico colpo di pistola, esagerato, se vogliamo, ma per lo meno più decente. Oggi se non paghi vieni classificato socio moroso, te ne vai e ti fai dimenticare per qualche mese. Poi ti fai ammettere in un altro Circolo e comincia la stessa storia, così tu vedi gente che passa da un Circolo all’altro e dopo anni di peregrinazioni te li ritrovi al Circolo di partenza, dove le versioni del fatto che provocò le dimissioni si sono, diciamo così, un po’ confuse. [...]»

Più avanti nel libro, l'espressione "venire su" appare di nuovo:

> A proposito, hai visto questi viveur **venuti su** ora, come si atteggiano a britannici? Cercano di essere composti, misurati, freddi, quando ordinano un whisky davanti a una signora. Poi sentono o vedono qualcosa o qualcuno che li interessa, e addio compostezza: cominciano a gesticolare come arabi, insomma uno sbracamento. Tuo fratello Ninì è meglio di questi, è più intelligente, più simpatico, ma esagera, vuole sbalordire ad ogni costo.

Non capisco il senso di "venire su" in questi brani. Me lo potreste spiegare, per favore?

Ho trovato la definizione di questa espressione sul [dizionario De Mauro](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/venire-su) e anche sul [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/venire) (al punto 4.b), ma non mi sembra che queste accezioni abbiano senso nel contesto di questi  passaggi. Ho cercato anche sul *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*, ma non sono riuscita a trovare questa locuzione (forse c'è e io non ho saputo individuarla: ricercare su questo dizionario non sempre mi risulta facile).

Comment: A naso sembra che si parli di _parvenu_ o simili.

Comment: Ah, può essere @DaG. Forse il senso sarebbe lo stesso che quello di questi esempi? https://books.google.es/books?id=Oc-QnlJLFEcC&q=%22persone+venute+su%22&dq=%22persone+venute+su%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiwt9PQksPrAhUL5uAKHTbUA8I4FBDoATACegQICRAB, 
https://books.google.es/books?id=RQowAQAAMAAJ&q=%22persone+venute+su%22&dq=%22persone+venute+su%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjX8eqvkcPrAhVt8OAKHcfTAv4Q6AEwCXoECAUQAQ, 
https://books.google.es/books?id=y3A4AAAAIAAJ&q=%22persone+venute+su%22&dq=%22persone+venute+su%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiwmvD0kcPrAhUR6OAKHTBnDNk4ChDoATAAegQIABAB

Comment: https://books.google.es/books?id=bMceAQAAIAAJ&q=%22persone+venute+su%22&dq=%22persone+venute+su%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiwmvD0kcPrAhUR6OAKHTBnDNk4ChDoATAGegQIBBAB

Comment: Sì, e “venire dal nulla” è un modo di dire:  https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/venire-dal-nulla

Comment: @Charo, direi di sì, anche se con “dal nulla” è più esplicito.

Comment: Sì, @Hachi, ma in questi esempi è "venire su dal nulla", che, da quello che ha detto DaG, immagino abbia il senso di essersi elevati a una condizione sociale e economica superiore partendo da origini umili.

Comment: Il senso di  “venire (su) dal nulla”  mi sembra molto chiaro. Il nulla sono “le umili origini”.

Comment: Il significato indicato nei commenti, "venire su (dal nulla)" è corretto; voglio sottolineare che l'espressione ha una sfumatura negativa, di disprezzo.

Comment: Infatti, l'espressione "venuto su dal nulla" si usa sul [GDLI](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI16/00374.jpg) nella definizione dell'aggettivo "rilevatìccio": "pervenuto  a  un’elevata  posi­zione  sociale  ed  economica  da  modeste  origini  fa­miliari; venuto su dal nulla".

Comment: @Charo - mai sentito “rilevaticcio”,  probabilmente un termine desueto. Parvenu è forse il termine più usato in questo senso.

Comment: si può usare anche "villan rifatto" :)